# Refactoring list comprehension with multiple conditions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
def detect_long_method(directory):
    path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(directory))
    output = lm.output_long_methods(directory)
    # print (output.stdout)
    split_lines = output.splitlines()
    output_lines = [output.decode('utf-8') for output in split_lines if len(output) > 3 and\
                    ('R0915' in output.decode('utf-8') or 'R0913' in output.decode('utf-8') or 'R0912' in output.decode('utf-8') or \
                    'R0904' in output.decode('utf-8') or 'R0902' in output.decode('utf-8'))]

    return output_lines
```

What this function does is, it runs a command line command and gets the stdout and assigns it to the variable `output`. It splits into lines using the `.splitlines()` function.

In the `output_lines`, it checks whether each line (they are in bytes) contains the word `R0915..etc.` and if the length of the line is over 3, then finally converts them into a string.

However, this is pretty slow and I feel like there is a way to write this more neatly and more efficiently.

Any help?

Comment: For starters, don't call `output.decode('utf-8')` every time you check if a string is in the output.

Comment: I somehow have to convert it into a string when I check if each string is included

Comment: Yeah. But you only have to do that once, not potentially, like 7 times

Comment: Also, it is probably more efficient to use a regex to check those things rather than multiple uses of `in`

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more efficient script:

```
import os
import re

def detect_long_method(directory):
    path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(directory))
    output = lm.output_long_methods(directory).decode('utf-8')
    # print (output.stdout)
    split_lines = output.splitlines()
    output_lines = [output for output in split_lines if len(output) > 3 and\
                    re.search("(R0915|R0913|R0912|R0904|R0902)", output) is not None]
    return output_lines
```

As juanpa.arrivillaga suggested, using [regular expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp), and calling `decode('utf-8')` once should lead to faster execution time.